# Null terminator for java

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, for String object, there is no null terminator. And Java uses offset to keep track of the length. However, is it the same case with char array?

For example:

```
char foo[] = new foo[5];
```

What is the actual size of the char array? Is it 5? Or it is 5 + 1? If I call

```
System.out.println(foo);
```

How does the function know when to reach the end of the char array? I noticed that there is a length field associated with char array in Java. Does it mean that Java also uses a variable to keep track of the length of char array instead of using null terminator?

Comment: You should read about arrays in Java. The type is irrelevant. Also, the most recent versions of the `String` class no longer use an `offset`. Also, your code won't compile.

Comment: The `length` of the array is `5` regardless of it's content.  If you have some special requirement, then it should documented (ie, *"The valid characters are all non-null values or the length of the array if no nulls exist"*)

Comment: Null-terminated strings are a C thing, and only that.  Other languages are free to work with strings as they see fit (e.g. preceded by a length field, `$` terminated, etc.)  An array in Java is just that - a collection of same-typed objects. There is no special treatment given for char arrays.

Comment: Everything in just Java knows it's size. How exactly does not need to concern you. That's one of the advantages of not having direct memory access / ways to buffer overflow.

Comment: @chrylis:  Wrong.  It will do something different with `char[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[An array of characters is not a String.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9) Neither is a String a `char[]`.**

By the JLS, they are two separate, well-defined entities.  Strings are immutable; arrays *aren't*.

The actual size of your `char[]` is also `5`, as [defined by the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3).  Since indexing is always zero-based, you can only access index locations `0-4`.

The call to `System.out.println(foo)` *typically* uses `foo.toString()` to do the work, but for a `char[]`, it's a bit special.  It eventually delegates to this method found in the `PrintStream` class:

```
private void write(char buf[]) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(buf);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush) {
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                    if (buf[i] == '\n')
                        out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

So it knows *exactly* how many elements it needs to print to the `out` stream by virtue of the loop.

Lastly (and likely ironically), a `String` object uses a `char[]` under the covers to store its values.  Since an array knows about its length, it delegates to it when pulling information about its size:

```
private final char value[];

public int length() {
    return value.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing `size` with `index`.  `size` is always how many elements, last index is how many elements - 1 `(c.length - 1)`. Same goes for String.  `size` is number of chararters, last character is number of characters - 1 `(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)`.